# tar - how to exclude like this: "/path/excludeRoot/**/directoryToExclude"

Tags: tar, exclude

I would like to exclude some directories from backup.
But not all with specific name - only those lying under specified root directory.
With rsync I would use exclude mask like this:

```
/path/excludeRoot/**/directoryToExclude
```

which means that all directories with name `directoryToExclude` lying
below `/path/excludeRoot` will be excluded.

On the other hand: each directory with name `directoryToExclude` but lying elsewhere will
be included

Is it possible to do it with tar?

Answer (score 1):

That is, unfortunately not straightforwardly possible as the `--exclude` family of options is not powerful enough.

One approach would be to obtain the list of objects using external program (say `find`) and then use `-T` switch to tell tar which files/objects should be included.

Quoting from the man page:

```
-T, --files-from FILE
  get names to extract or create from FILE
```

If the filenames contain special symbols (and/or spaces) I would add `--null` to the tar command line; to generate the list I would also use `-print0` with find -- to separate the files/dirs with NUL (`\000`) character.